# What happens if I have two integrated video cards?

Tags: motherboard, amd-radeon

I'm thinking about building a computer for my parents. Since they don't play video games I thought I'd get them a motherboard/cpu with an integrated video card. The motherboard I'm looking at is an AMD with a built in Radeon card and coincidentally the CPU I'm looking at (also AMD) has a built in Radeon card. My question is will this cause problems? Will the computer run video faster because of the two integrated cards or will I have to disable one of them? Thanks for all the help!

The motherboard is 
GIGABYTE GA-78LMT-USB3 AM3+ AMD 760G HDMI USB 3.0 Micro ATX AMD Motherboard 
(http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128565)

and the CPU is
AMD Athlon II X4 640 Propus 3.0GHz Socket AM3 95W Quad-Core Desktop Processor
(http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103871)

Comment: It depends if the motherboard itself can even support the GPU in the CPU.  If it can't, you can still use the processor, but not the integrated GPU.  And no the computer won't run faster with both, you can only use one to drive your primary display (it *might* be possible to use the other for CUDA/OpenCL tasks, but this is very application specific).

Comment: More information is required to answer this question.

Comment: What motherboard? What CPU? (Are you sure the motherboard actually has integrated video, rather than just the hardware necessary to make the CPU's integrated video work?)

Comment: Jon, please **register your account** here. It seems you've lost your cookie, which is bad because you might be creating duplicate unregistered users all over the place.

Comment: I was wondering why I couldn't add comments :) I'm registered, I just wasn't logged in. I added the motherboard and CPU to the post. I don't really know anything about video cards. This is the first time I've ever built a computer so I'm just wondering if this is a waste of money, a good idea, or if it will cause unforeseen consequences down the road. Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Specific case

The Athlon II X4 640 does **not** have an integrated GPU.

None of these pages mentions a GPU:

- Newegg: [AMD Athlon II X4 640 Propus...](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103871) (link you provided)
- AMD: [AMD Athlon II X4 640 (ADX640WFGMBOX) Details](http://shop.amd.com/us/All/Detail/All/ADX640WFGMBOX#Details)
- Wikipedia: [Athlon II # Propus (45 nm SOI with immersion lithography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athlon_II#Propus_.2845_nm_SOI_with_immersion_lithography.29)

#### General case

> [W]ill this cause problems?

Most likely, no. There are two plausible scenarios:

- The motherboard's chipset does not support the CPU's integrated GPU.
- The motherboard is prepared to use two GPUs. Some laptops do this.

> Will the computer run video faster because of the two integrated cards or will I have to disable one of them?

There is hybrid CrossFire to use an integrated and a dedicated GPU for video output, but I'm not aware of something similar for two integrated GPUs.

However, if the GPUs and the chipset support it, you can use one GPU for video output and the other for different tasks (e.g., audio/video transcoding).

Comment: I actually linked the wrong CPU by accident. It doesn't matter though because your answer solved my question. Thanks!